# How to set a common style for a swing application so that it will reflect in all the screen?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

My Java application consists of 150 to 200 Swing-based forms for which I need to set a common style which should reflect across the application.

For example: If I want to change a background color for all the Panels used, I have to make the change in one place so that it reflects everywhere.(Like CSS in web development).

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: I added the tag that effectively answers the question.  Put 'look feel java tutorial' into your favorite search engine and go from there.

Comment: Suggestion:[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter that can be answered by looking at the new tag added.

Comment: [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MadProgrammer's advice to use a custom look and feel, I explored the option and tried out one on available on the web called `Squareness`.

Go to the following page and download squareness:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/squareness/files/Java%20Look%20And%20Feel/2.3.0/

1. Download the `squareness_jlf-2.3.0.zip` and unzip the file.
2. Add the squareness.jar file to your build path / class path.
3. Then, within your main() method, just put the following piece of code:

   `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("net.beeger.squareness.SquarenessLookAndFeel");`

The page also has the source code available in `squareness_jlf_src-2.3.0.zip` so you can take a look at how the `net.beeger.squareness.SquarenessLookAndFeel` class has been implemented and it can probably help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score -1):

Create a Customized Panel that extends Swing's `JPanel`. Put all your customization here.

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

    public CustomPanel(){
        // Init customization here
        loadStyle();
    }

    private void loadStyle(){
        // Read an XML or Properties file containing 
        // necessary formatting info
    }
}
```

Then create all your 150-200 forms by extending `CustomPanel`. This way, by modifying the XML, you can make the change reflect all your screens in one go!

```
public class Screen1Panel extends CustomPanel {
    //Screen specific code goes here...
}
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: `// necessary formatting info .. or even better CSS!` Perhaps you're thinking of Java-FX..

Comment: No, I mean Java Swing. The OP needs one place where he can keep all formatting options, so a properties file or XML can be used. If he wants true CSS support, he'll have to interpret CSS probably using a 3rd party library. But if the mention of CSS is confusing, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What @MadProgrammer said.  Much more the 'Swing' way of going about this, and without needing custom panels (which would presumably require a major rewrite for the 150-200 existing views), parsing XML or extra APIs to interpret and apply the styles.

Comment: @anarcon what u suggested is already in my mind but the problem here is i need to write such customized code for all the components like label,radio button,tabbed pane etc.. consider how much i need to write thats why asked something similar to CSS but not exactly the same.Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please provide some more detail about UIManager since i dont have much knowledge in swing.

Comment: [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: @madprorammer i got your point but, with UIManager we can use the LAFS which is already available but we could not customise the UI colors according to our wish thats the problem. is there any solution available ? please suggest !!!

Comment: @sri, is this an existing application or something that you're starting to build?

Comment: See if this link helps in creating a custom look and feel like MadProgrammer suggested: 

https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html

Comment: @anacron ya this is an existing project.what i need is i need to have single java file where i will provide my custimsation like for eg. font color , panel background color , border width and color etc.,button size so that it should reflect accross the application

Comment: @sri, Try out the following custom LookAndFeel called Squareness:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/squareness/files/Java%20Look%20And%20Feel/2.3.0/

Download the squareness_jlf-2.3.0.zip and unzip the file.
Add the squareness.jar file to your build path / class path.
Then, within your main() method, just put the following piece of code:
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("net.beeger.squareness.SquarenessLookAndFeel");

The page also has the source code available so you can look at how the net.beeger.squareness.SquarenessLookAndFeel has been implemented and it can probably help you acheive your goal.